# Ruby: combining arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to combine these arrays:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

[["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["e","f"]]
```

in the following way:

```
[[1,2,3,"a","b"], [4,5,6,"c","d"], [7,8,9,"e","f"]]
```

but I'm not managing to find the correct answer.

Comment: What have you tried? You can't just dump requirements on us, and say "thanks". This is not a coder-for-hire site. You need to post your attempted solution for us to help you find the reason it isn't working.

Comment: I am sorry meagar. I'm quite new to ruby and SO. I have tried array1 + array2, zip and few other things I've found on the net. I haven't included them, since I didn't think they add to my question.

Comment: You certainly didn't allow much time for others to post answers. Seeing the green checkmark flash on after a mere 15 minutes is disappointing.

Comment: ok, I'll keep that in mind for the next time. Too bad I can only give one checkmark, but I've upvoted both answers. I appreciate all the help a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, interweave the arrays with [`Enumerable#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), then [`flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-flatten) each element in the new array:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["e","f"]]

a.zip(b).map(&:flatten)
# => [[1, 2, 3, "a", "b"], [4, 5, 6, "c", "d"], [7, 8, 9, "e", "f"]]
```

If you're unfamiliar, the "pretzel colon syntax" `foo(&:bar)` is equivalent to `foo { |x| x.bar }` (not really *syntax*, just a method call under the hood).

Comment: Enumerable is a fantastic collection of methods. Anyone new to Ruby should spend some time reading through what's in that tool-chest. Hadn't heard it called "prezel-colon" either, so that's new.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
def combine(a,b)
  a.zip(b).map { |a,b| a+b }
end

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

combine a, [[4],[5],[6]]
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 5], [7, 8, 9, 6]]
combine a, [[4],[5],[[6,7],[8,9]]]
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 5], [7, 8, 9, [6, 7], [8, 9]]]
```

`flatten` does not give the second result.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=[["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["e","f"]]

a.zip(b).map{|x| x.flatten 1}
```

Explanation :

The `zip` method expects variable number of arguments and returns an array of arrays that contain corresponding elements from each array. That is, an element-wise merge with the original array.
Example Code:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].zip([42, 23, 16, 15, 8]) #=> [[4, 42], [8, 23], [15, 16], [16, 15], [23, 8], [42, nil]]
```

The `flatten` method returns a one-dimensional array representation of the array. It recursively picks out all elements from the inner-arrays and lays them out in the outermost array.

```
[4, [8], [15],[[[[30,[[[[6]]]]]]],15], [16, [23, 42]]].flatten #=> [4, 8, 15, 30, 6, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

so in above example `a.zip(b)` will return `[[[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b"]], [[4, 5, 6], ["c", "d"]], [[7, 8, 9], ["e", "f"]]]` and then on each element `flatten` is applied which will removed the nested array and give us the required result.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Why would you post an answer that is the same as one posted earlier?